# Ion Representations

Tags: ions

Some books put dots around ions, enclose them in braces and then put an integer over them to signify the negative charge, in such representations, the integer is only a way to represent the charge and is not supposed to be added with the other valance electrons when calculating the total no. of electrons, right?

Eg: O with 8 dots around it, in braces with -2 over it, means that ion has only 10 electrons and not 12, right?

Comment: Read up about Lewis Structures. That may be what you are looking for. the dots signify the electrons.

Answer (score 2):

The neutral oxygen atom has 8 electrons, 2 on the inner shell K, and 6 on the outer shell L (or valence shell). So this neutral atom is represented by the letter O with six dots around it. It is possible to add two more electrons. This makes the oxide ion $\ce{O^{2-}}$. This ion can be represented with all its outer electrons, with 8 dots. This symbol $\ce{O}$ with its eight dots is enclosed in braces, before adding the total charge (2-) over it.